# IM programs for Ubuntu that support sending message to group

Tags: ubuntu, instant-messaging

Is there any IM programs in Ubuntu that support sending message to group (I can select a number of contact and then send a group message).
It's available for decade on Yahoo Messenger for Windows but I cannot find it inside Pidgin nor Empathy.

Answer (score 0):

In Pidgin:

1. right-click the first contact and select Initial Chat
2. drag and drop another contact from the contacts list to the list of users in the conversation window
3. report 2 until you have added everyone
4. start your conversation

This only works if all the contacts are on the same network and that network supports this form of chat though (i.e. all the people you want to contact are on MSN/Live).

Not perfect, but it at least works.

Comment: Hi! I cannot find `Initial Chat`, but there is an `IM` menu item there. (I'm using Pidgin 2.4.1). When I drag contact to the conversation windows, it open a new tab. I guess it's not what you were talking about. Please advice.

Comment: I'm using a later version of Pidgin (2.6.5) - perhaps the feature was added somewhere between the versions we have?